# Why can't I make my own test database for my django project?

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am currently deciding what testing packages to use with my django project, specifically how to populate data before I run tests.  I have looked into:

1. Fixtures: Many people seem to be against this since modifying JSON can be difficult and hard to maintain.
2. Factory boy: My project has a lot of hierarchy to it, so I feel like creating an object from a model that is really low in the hierarchy is really slow.

The idea I have in my mind is to just make a database that I will always run tests against.  Since I know what data is in it, shouldn't it work similarly to fixtures without the hassle of JSON?  Since I haven't seen this idea through my research, I assume this is a bad idea.  Why is it a bad idea though?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe I am misunderstanding but django by default uses Sqlite, and changing to MySql or Postgres is as easy as changing your `settings.py`.

Comment: @GregSchmit: he is asking about different ways to get test data in a database for unit testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually test with factory boy? With an in-memory sqlite database it is very fast, in my experience, and super convenient with hierarchies.

Your database idea is more or less the same as fixtures -- you could use the database to create JSON fixtures by running the `dumpdata` management command on it, and maintain your test data in the database instead of in the JSON files.

Some reasons to prefer factory boy over a test database:

- The data is generated right there in the test, so it's immediately obvious what happens and which fields are relevant for the test.
- The data comes with the test code, no extra files or database dumps to manage.
- Factory boy is very good with hierarchies ("I want an instance of this instance with all fields the default value, except this one field six steps up in the hierarchy" -- `instance = InstanceFactory.build(series__study__patient__archive__project__algorithm_type='foo')`)
- Sometimes an object doesn't have to be saved to the database at all to have its methods tested, in that case factory boy's `.build()` is very fast.
- Instead of picking interesting border cases for the current test, you will be tempted to just re-use the stuff you already have in the database and not find bugs.
- Maybe the different values you need to test with can't exist in the database at the same time due to uniqueness constraints.

There are probably more, but I need to sleep.